# Xamarin: Unable to extract central square of photo in Android/iOS

Tags: xamarin

I am trying to get an image using the camera.  The image is to be 256x256 and I want it to come from the centre of a photo taken using the camera on a phone. I found this code at: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37647/cross-platform-crop-image-view

I am using this code for Android...

```
public byte[] CropPhoto(byte[] photoToCropBytes, Rectangle rectangleToCrop, double outputWidth, double outputHeight)
        {
            using (var photoOutputStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // Load the bitmap
                var inSampleSize = CalculateInSampleSize((int)rectangleToCrop.Width, (int)rectangleToCrop.Height, (int)outputWidth, (int)outputHeight);
                var options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
                //options.InPurgeable = true;   see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html
                using (var photoToCropBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(photoToCropBytes, 0, photoToCropBytes.Length, options))
                {
                    var matrix = new Matrix();
                    var martixScale = outputWidth / rectangleToCrop.Width * inSampleSize;
                    matrix.PostScale((float)martixScale, (float)martixScale);
                    using (var photoCroppedBitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(photoToCropBitmap, (int)(rectangleToCrop.X / inSampleSize), (int)(rectangleToCrop.Y / inSampleSize), (int)(rectangleToCrop.Width / inSampleSize), (int)(rectangleToCrop.Height / inSampleSize), matrix, true))
                    {
                        photoCroppedBitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, photoOutputStream);
                    }
                }

                return photoOutputStream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static int CalculateInSampleSize(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, int outputWidth, int outputHeight) 
        {
            //see http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

            int inSampleSize = 1;       //default

            if (inputHeight > outputHeight || inputWidth > outputWidth) {

                int halfHeight = inputHeight / 2;
                int halfWidth = inputWidth / 2;

                // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
                // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
                while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > outputHeight && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > outputWidth) 
                {
                    inSampleSize *= 2;
                }
            }

            return inSampleSize;
        }
```

and this code for iOS...

```
    public byte[] CropPhoto(byte[] photoToCropBytes, Xamarin.Forms.Rectangle 

rectangleToCrop, double outputWidth, double outputHeight)
        {
            byte[] photoOutputBytes;

            using (var data = NSData.FromArray(photoToCropBytes))
            {
                using (var photoToCropCGImage = UIImage.LoadFromData(data).CGImage)
                {
                    //crop image
                    using (var photoCroppedCGImage = photoToCropCGImage.WithImageInRect(new CGRect((nfloat)rectangleToCrop.X, (nfloat)rectangleToCrop.Y, (nfloat)rectangleToCrop.Width, (nfloat)rectangleToCrop.Height)))
                    {
                        using (var photoCroppedUIImage = UIImage.FromImage(photoCroppedCGImage))
                        {
                            //create a 24bit RGB image to the output size
                            using (var cGBitmapContext = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, (int)outputWidth, (int)outputHeight, 8, (int)(4 * outputWidth), CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
                            {
                                var photoOutputRectangleF = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, (float)outputWidth, (float)outputHeight);

                                // draw the cropped photo resized 
                                cGBitmapContext.DrawImage(photoOutputRectangleF, photoCroppedUIImage.CGImage);

                                //get cropped resized photo
                                var photoOutputUIImage = UIKit.UIImage.FromImage(cGBitmapContext.ToImage());

                                //convert cropped resized photo to bytes and then stream
                                using (var photoOutputNsData = photoOutputUIImage.AsJPEG())
                                {
                                    photoOutputBytes = new Byte[photoOutputNsData.Length];
                                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(photoOutputNsData.Bytes, photoOutputBytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(photoOutputNsData.Length));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return photoOutputBytes;
        }
```

I am struggling to work out exactly what the parameters are to call the function.

Currently, I am doing the following:

```
        double cropSize = Math.Min(DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width, DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height);
        double left = (DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Width - cropSize) / 2.0;
        double top = (DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height - cropSize) / 2.0;

        // Get a square resized and cropped from the top image as a byte[]
        _imageData = mediaService.CropPhoto(_imageData, new Rectangle(left, top, cropSize, cropSize), 256, 256);
```

I was expecting this to crop the image to the central square (in portrait mode side length would be the width of the photo) and then scale it down to a 256x256 image.  But it never picks the centre of the image.

Has anyone ever used this code and can tell me what I need to pass in for the 'rectangleToCrop' parameter?

Note:  Both Android and iOS give the same image, just not the central part that I was expecting.

Comment: why are you using `DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo`?  Shouldn't you be using the width and height of the image instead?

Comment: Is that not the same thing?  I assumed the image was as big as the screen.  How can I determine the size of the image?

Comment: Inside the two O/S specific routines, there is a "photoToCrop...".  This has a Width/Height property.  I'll check these out tomorrow and update this ticket if I fix it.

Comment: Jason you were correct, but I had to mess about with the in-ards of those two routines to get them both to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the two routines I used:

Android:

```
public byte[] ResizeImageAndCropToSquare(byte[] rawPhoto, int outputSize)
{
    // Create object of bitmapfactory's option method for further option use
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    // InPurgeable is used to free up memory while required
    options.InPurgeable = true;

    // Get the original image
    using (var originalImage = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(rawPhoto, 0, rawPhoto.Length, options))
    {
        // The shortest edge will determine the size of the square image
        int cropSize = Math.Min(originalImage.Width, originalImage.Height);

        int left = (originalImage.Width - cropSize) / 2;
        int top = (originalImage.Height - cropSize) / 2;

        using (var squareImage = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(originalImage, left, top, cropSize, cropSize))
        {
            // Resize the square image to the correct size of an Avatar
            using (var resizedImage = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(squareImage, outputSize, outputSize, true))
            {
                // Return the raw data of the resized image
                using (MemoryStream resizedImageStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    // Resize the image maintaining 100% quality
                    resizedImage.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, resizedImageStream);
                    return resizedImageStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

iOS:
        private const int BitsPerComponent = 8;

```
    public byte[] ResizeImageAndCropToSquare(byte[] rawPhoto, int outputSize)
    {
        using (var data = NSData.FromArray(rawPhoto))
        {
            using (var photoToCrop = UIImage.LoadFromData(data).CGImage)
            {
                nint photoWidth = photoToCrop.Width;
                nint photoHeight = photoToCrop.Height;

                nint cropSize = photoWidth < photoHeight ? photoWidth : photoHeight;
                nint left = (photoWidth - cropSize) / 2;
                nint top = (photoHeight - cropSize) / 2;

                // Crop image
                using (var photoCropped = photoToCrop.WithImageInRect(new CGRect(left, top, cropSize, cropSize)))
                {
                    using (var photoCroppedUIImage = UIImage.FromImage(photoCropped))
                    {
                        // Create a 24bit RGB image of output size
                        using (var cGBitmapContext = new CGBitmapContext(IntPtr.Zero, outputSize, outputSize, BitsPerComponent, outputSize << 2, CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst))
                        {
                            var photoOutputRectangleF = new RectangleF(0f, 0f, outputSize, outputSize);

                            // Draw the cropped photo resized 
                            cGBitmapContext.DrawImage(photoOutputRectangleF, photoCroppedUIImage.CGImage);

                            // Get cropped resized photo
                            var photoOutputUIImage = UIImage.FromImage(cGBitmapContext.ToImage());

                            // Convert cropped resized photo to bytes and then stream
                            using (var photoOutputNsData = photoOutputUIImage.AsPNG())
                            {
                                var rawOutput = new byte[photoOutputNsData.Length];
                                Marshal.Copy(photoOutputNsData.Bytes, rawOutput, 0, Convert.ToInt32(photoOutputNsData.Length));

                                return rawOutput;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```